# javascript window location get path of website to redirect to between localhost and actual domain

Tags: javascript, redirect, href

I want to be able to redirect my user on logout of my website back to the homepage/login, this would be easy to do if I just redirected to the website itself, IE `http://www.example.com/` however, how could I determine the root folder path for my site when it's on localhost?

for example, some of my websites are in: `localhost/folder1/websiteBackup/` and some are in: `localhost/`

what would the best way to combine it so one line of code will work for both the localhost and the domain name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a relative path instead of an absolute one. For example, instead of

```
/somePage.html
```

you might write

```
../../somePage.html
```

If the script is shared and you don't know where it's going to be relative to the page, consider developing on separate `<VirtualHost>`s so that your environments match.

Answer (score 0):

this is what works for me..try your luck

```
  url:'<%=VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Include/ctnrls/Data.aspx") %>',
```

but I am mapping my virtual path in IIS

Answer (score 0):

```
document.location = 
    document.location.href.indexOf('localhost') >=0 ?
    document.location.href.split('localhost')[1] + 'index.htm' : 
    'index.htm';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use some server side session variables (PHP/ASP) and assign root path to them. then you can use them any time you want.

```
session("rootPath") = "/RootFolder/your-filename" (for ASP/VBScript)
```

Later use them in you JS code to redirect.

```
var path = '<%= session("rootPath")%> (JS code)';
```

Check similar question I asked in here for more info on Relative path, Relative Root path and Absolute root path.